# Location is not coming up in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-community, help, developer-org

I have created a text box "Customer Entererd Location Name" and want this picklist to look up to user location and do an auto search . It should show up all the existing location when user enters keystroke in this text box. Need to have a textbox where users can enter a location and enable an auto-complete feature on keystroke to show the location based on logged in user account associated ebs id and product type from location master2 object.
[image] .

html

```
   <template>
    <lightning-card title="Claims Details New Section">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Product1__c' value={op1} 
            variant="label-stacked"
            onchange={handleselect} required></lightning-input-field>
            <div>
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                            
                            <div class={txtclassname} data-id="resultBox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
                                    
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon iconheight">
                                            <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                        </span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <lightning-input required={required} read-only={inputReadOnly}  data-id="userinput" label='Customer Entered Location Name' name="searchText" onchange={searchField} value={selectRecordName} onblur={manual} style="padding-left:30px" class="leftspace" autocomplete="off" onclick={searchField}></lightning-input>
                                 <!--- <lightning-button label="Click To Allow Custom Location Name" onclick={allowcustom}></lightning-button>
                                  --><div if:true={iconFlag}>
                                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right iconheight">
                                            <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:search" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                        </span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div if:true={clearIconFlag}>
                                        <button class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-button slds-button_icon iconheight" onclick={resetData}>
                                            <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:clear" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Clear</span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            
                                <!-- Second part display result -->
                                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                                        <template for:each={searchRecords} for:item="serecord">
                                            <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" key={serecord.Id}>
                                                
                                                <div data-id={serecord.Id} data-name={serecord.Customer_Entered_Location_Name__c} onclick={setSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                                    <span class="slds-media__figure">
                                                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                                                            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span class="slds-media__body">
                                                        <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{serecord.Customer_Entered_Location_Name__c}</span>
                                                        <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">{objectName} • {serecord.Customer_Entered_Location_Name__c} • Branch Name • {serecord.Brink_s_Servicing_Branch__c}</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                                </div> 
                                <div if:true={messageFlag}>
                                    No result found.
                                </div>
                                <div if:true={LoadingText}>
                                    Loading...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <lightning-input-field field-name='Brink_s_Servicing_Branch__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='of_Locations__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Date_of_Service__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Date_Loss_Recognized__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Dollar_Amount_of_Claim__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Type_of_Variance__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Description'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='PortalEmailReceivers__c'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-button label="Previous" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form> 
          </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

---

```
          }
          else{
            element.fieldset[y].value=this.fname;
            element.fieldset[y].required=false;
          }
                  }
                  //Brink_s_Courier__c
                  if(element.fieldset[y].fun=="this.handleChange" ||element.fieldset[y].field=='Brink_s_Courier__c')
                  {
                   element.fieldset[y].fun=this.handleChange;
                  }
                }
                this.field.push(element);
    
            }
        });
       // this.field=x;
                console.log("locerr",error);
            });
        }
        else{
            var res=this.cjson;
            this.locid='';
            this.branchname='';
            this.Address='';
           // this.fname='';
           this.branchId='';
            this.field=[];
            res.forEach(element => {
    
            // if(element.op1.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()==this.op1.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()&&element.op2==this.op2.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim() && element.op3.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()==this.op3.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim())
             {
              //  alert(JSON.stringify(element));
              console.log("Eselected",JSON.stringify(element));
             
             for(var y=0;y<element.fieldset.length;y++)
             {
               if(element.fieldset[y].value=="this.locid"||element.fieldset[y].field=='ATM_Location_Name__c'||element.fieldset[y].field=='Requestors_Location_ID__c')
               {
                element.fieldset[y].value=this.locid;
               }
               if(element.fieldset[y].value=="this.branchname" ||element.fieldset[y].field=='Brinks_Branch_Name__c')
               {
                element.fieldset[y].value=this.branchId;
               }
              // if(element.fieldset[y].value=="this.Address" ||element.fieldset[y].field=='Address_of_Service_Location__c'|| element.fieldset[y].field=='Service_Location_Address__c')
              // {
              //  element.fieldset[y].value=this.Address;
              // }
              // if(element.fieldset[y].value=="this.fname" ||element.fieldset[y].field=='Financial_Institution__c')
               {
                if(this.fname)
          {
       element.fieldset[y].value=this.fname;
          }
          else{
            element.fieldset[y].value=this.fname;
            element.fieldset[y].required=false;
          }
               }
               //Brink_s_Courier__c
               if(element.fieldset[y].fun=="this.handleChange" ||element.fieldset[y].field=='Brink_s_Courier__c')
               {
                element.fieldset[y].fun=this.handleChange;
               }
             }
             this.field.push(element);
    
         
        }
            
        })
    }
        }
        setVal(event)
        {
            console.log("222event",event.target.name);
            if(event.target.name=="locid")
            {
                this.val=this.locid;
            }
            if(event.target.name=="branchname")
            {
                this.val=this.branchname;
            }
            //branchname
        }
    
        
        handleChange(event)
        {
    this.value=event.detail.value
    //console.log("h1"+event.detail.name)
    if(this.value=='No')
    {
        this.ncourf=true;
    }
    else if(this.value=='Yes'){
        this.ncourf=false;
    }
        }
    
        handleSuccess2(event)
        {
            console.log("111data",JSON.stringify(event.detail.fields));
      //   this.s2=false;  
      this.loaded=true;
     var x=event.detail.fields;
     event.preventDefault(); 
    //x.branchId=this.branchid;
    x.contact=this.contactid;
    x.account=this.account.Id;
    x.lname=this.branchname;
    x.location_id=this.alocid;
    x.phonenumber=this.user.Phone;
    x.accname=this.account.Name;
    x.ctype=this.op3;
    x.Product1__c=this.op1;
    //x.Category__c=this.op2;
    x.Brinks_Branch_Name__c=this.branchId?this.branchId:x.Brinks_Branch_Name__c;
    x.Customer_Entered_Location_Name__c=this.lname;
    console.log("req12"+JSON.stringify(x))
    createCase({params:JSON.stringify(x)}).then((res)=>{
    console.log("post",res);
    this.loaded=false;
    this.rid=JSON.parse(res)[0].Id;
    this.c=JSON.parse(res)[0];
    this.s2=false;
    
    })
    
    
    
    
        }
        /*get acceptedFormats() {
            return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
        }*/
        
        finish(event)
        {
           
            this.s3=false;
            const toastEvnt = new  ShowToastEvent( {
                title: 'Service Request Created Successfully!',
                message:  "Case Id:"+ this.rid,
                variant: 'success' ,
            });
            
            this.dispatchEvent (toastEvnt);
          
        }
      
        prev(event)
        {
            this.d=true;
            this.field=[];
            this.ncourf=false;
            this.dcheck=true;
            this.mp=false;
            this.op1='';
            
        }
        prev1(event)
        {
            this.s2=true;
            this.d=false;
            
        }
       
    
        cnavigate()
        {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: `/case/${this.rid}`
                }
            }
          //  false // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
          );
        }
    /*--- adding autosearch feature ----*/
    
    searchField(event) {
        var currentText = event.target.value;
        this.LoadingText = true;
        this.inputReadOnly=false;
        console.log("etext",currentText);
        console.log("ebs"+this.registry_EBS_id)
        this.currenttext2=event.target.value;
        console.log("ptype"+this.op1);
        if(currentText.length==0)
        {
            this.LoadingText = false;
        }
       if(currentText.length>1)
       {
        getLocationList({Id:event.target.value,ebs_id:this.registry_EBS_id,ptype:this.op1})
        .then(result => {
            var x=JSON.parse(result);
           x.unshift({"Customer_Entered_Location_Name__c":"Not Found. Click To Enter Your Location Name","currentRecId":"1234567"});
            this.searchRecords= x;
           // this.LoadingText = false;
           // console.log("locres",x);
            this.txtclassname =   this.searchRecords.length > 0 ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
            if(currentText.length > 0 &&  this.searchRecords.length == 0) {
                this.messageFlag = true;
                this.currenttext=currentText;
               // this.callBlur(currenttext);
            }
            else {
                this.messageFlag = false;
            }
    
            if(this.selectRecordId != null && this.selectRecordId.length > 0) {
                this.iconFlag = false;
                this.clearIconFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.iconFlag = true;
                this.clearIconFlag = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
        
    }
    
    setSelectedRecord(event) {
    
        var currentRecId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name=="Not Found. Click To Enter Your Location Name"?this.currenttext2:event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        this.iconFlag = false;
        this.clearIconFlag = true;
        this.selectRecordName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name=="Not Found. Click To Enter Your Location Name"?this.currenttext2:event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        this.selectRecordId = currentRecId;
     this.inputReadOnly = true;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selectName, currentRecId}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        //alert(selectName);
        console.log("selected11",currentRecId);
       if(selectName.length > 0)
       {
    this.callBlur(currentRecId,selectName);
   }
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}

resetData(event) {
    this.selectRecordName = "";
    this.selectRecordId = "";
    this.inputReadOnly = false;
    this.iconFlag = true;
    this.clearIconFlag = false;
   
}
handleUploadFinished(event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
     //   const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    //  alert("upload finished"+this.rid);
        uploadfile({Id:this.rid})
    .then(result => {
                //alert(result);
        });
       // alert("No. of files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
        
        
    }
manual(event)
{
  //  alert(this.currenttext);
  //  alert(event.target.value);
    if(this.currenttext==event.target.value)
    {

        this.callBlur(event.target.value);
    }
}}
```

Comment: The "customer Entered Location name should auto populate location name by looking up to the user ebs id each time an user tries to choose their location. For if they enter D all the options for location should appear in the dropdown which would include all locations starting with D like Dallas, Detroit